# How to show HTTP status text in the Chrome Inspector?

Tags: http, web-inspector

[Screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/osAlQ.png)

[Screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3tpCO.png)

I see status codes like 200, but not status texts such as "OK". How do I enable status text?

Comment: HTTP/2 doesn't have this text at all anymore. Doesn't look like you can at least in this screen.